# SQLAlchemy to join to same table on a column, but also need data from other columns in result

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Assuming I have a model defined as so:

```
class DstEntry(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'dst_entry'

    id = Column('id', DBKeyType, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(64))
    ip_addr = Column(IPAddress)
    logical_device_ip = Column(String(64))
```

And I have data like so:

```
id   name      ip_addr      logical_device_ip
--------------------------------------------------
1    l3dst     3.3.3.3/32   192.168.99.151
2    httpdst   1.1.1.1/32   192.168.99.152   <===
3    httpdst2  2.2.2.0/24   192.168.99.151
4    dddd      1.1.1.1/32   192.168.99.153   <===
5    httpdst   1.1.1.1/32   192.168.99.151   <===
6    aadst     4.4.4.4/32   192.168.99.153
```

I would like to be able to perform a query to eventually get something that tell me:

```
ip_addr     logical_device_ip
--------------------------------------------------
1.1.1.1/32  192.168.99.151, 192.168.99.152, 192.168.99.153
3.3.3.3/32  192.168.99.151
2.2.2.0/24  192.168.99.151
4.4.4.4/32  192.168.99.153
```

How do I do this with sqlalchemy?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
res = session.query(
       DstEntry.ip_addr,
       func.group_concat(DstEntry.logical_device_ip)
       ).group_by(DstEntry.ip_addr)

for r in res:
    print r
```

**Note:**

1. `logical_device_ip` in the result are concatenated with `,` as separator. If you want to add a space character to the separator, do this instead

   ```
   res = session.query(
          DstEntry.ip_addr,
          func.group_concat(DstEntry.logical_device_ip.op('SEPARATOR')(', '))
          ).group_by(DstEntry.ip_addr)
   ```
2. The raw SQL query for MySQL is:

   ```
   SELECT ip_addr,
          GROUP_CONCAT(logical_device_ip) AS logical_device_ip
   FROM dst_entry
   GROUP BY ip_addr;
   ```